# My password reset view in django shows up only when the user has logged in but not when logged out

Tags: python, django

When I click on forgot password django takes me to another page other than the password reset page, but this doesn't happen when I am logged in  only happen when I am logged out.
I want it to happen when logged out
Please help!
[This is the page that renders after clicking on forgot password when logged out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04CtN.png)
[This is the page that should render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyi7H.png)

> views.py

```
    @login_required
def password_reset_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        password_reset_form = PasswordResetForm(request.POST)
        if password_reset_form.is_valid():
            data = password_reset_form.cleaned_data['email']
            associated_users = User.objects.filter(Q(email=data))
            if associated_users.exists():
                for user in associated_users:
                    subject = "Password Reset Requested"
                    email_template_name = "password/password_reset_email.txt"
                    c = {
                        "email": user.email,
                        'domain': '127.0.0.1:8000',
                        'site_name': 'Website',
                        "uid": urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                        "user": user,
                        'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
                        'protocol': 'http',
                    }
                    email = render_to_string(email_template_name, c)
                    try:
                        send_mail(subject, email, 'sample@gmail.com', [user.email], fail_silently=False)
                    except BadHeaderError:
                        return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
                    messages.success(request, 'A message with reset password instructions has been sent to your inbox.')
                    return redirect("/password_reset/done/")
                messages.error(request, 'An invalid email has been entered.')
    password_reset_form = PasswordResetForm()
    return render(request=request, template_name="password/password_reset.html",
                  context={"form": password_reset_form})
```

> urls.py

```
   urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', signup),
    path('login/', login_request),
    path('logout/', logout_request),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('Admin/Links/', update_profile_links),
    path('Admin/Appearance/', update_profile_appearance),
    path('Admin/Social_Links/', update_profile_social),
    path('Admin/Profile/<str:username>/', profile_view),
    path('password_reset/', password_reset_request),   
    path('password_reset/done/',auth_views.PasswordResetDone
    View.as_view(template_name='password/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="password/password_reset_confirm.html"), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='password/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete'),
    path('delete_account/', delete_user)
            ]
```

> project/urls.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('Home.urls')),
    path('', include('UserManagement.urls')),
    path('', include('UserLinks.urls')),
```

]

Answer (score 0):

can you try to enter while logged out and print(request.method) perhapes it is not a POST method ?? Furthermore could you please post the code of the logged out page and where it sends you to this forget password page.

Comment: Thank you @Katout999 for your response! But I did the most silly mistake that is the (login_required) at the top